Derivative of the integral of a function with respect to that function
Let $(\mathcal{X}, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f : \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $g : \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ where
$$g = \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}\!f} \int_\mu f$$
What is the correct way to define $g$? One candidate is
$$g(x) = \mu(\{x\})$$
However, $\{x\}$ might not be measurable, i.e. $\{x\} \not\in \Sigma$.
Other candidates are
\begin{align}
g(x) &= \mu^*(\{x\}) \\
g(x) &= \mu_*(\{x\})
\end{align}
where $\mu^*$ and $\mu_*$ are the upper and lower measures, respectively:
\begin{align}
\mu^*(\mathcal{B}) &= \inf \{\mu(\mathcal{A}) \mid \mathcal{A} \in \Sigma, \mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}\} \\
\mu_*(\mathcal{B}) &= \sup \{\mu(\mathcal{A}) \mid \mathcal{A} \in \Sigma, \mathcal{B} \supseteq \mathcal{A}\}
\end{align}
Notably,
\begin{align}
\mu_*(\{x\}) = \begin{cases}
0 & \{x\} \not\in \Sigma \\
\mu(\{x\}) & \{x\} \in \Sigma
\end{cases}
\end{align}
What is the correct approach? Is there a standard name in the literature for this?
